# Spark Unit Test Fails with "ExceptionInInitializerError" with latest version of "json4s-jackson"

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

We have some spark/scala unit test cases written in the below framework: 
 - https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base

For some of our features we upgraded "json4s-jackson" to "3.5.3" - after upgrading jackson version to latest all our unit test cases are failing with the below error:

> [info] #getPageViewWithMember [info]
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec
>   *** ABORTED *** [info]   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:272)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
>   [info]   ... [info]   Cause:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible
>   Jackson version: 2.8.4 [info]   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
>   [info]   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
>   [info]   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:745)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:272)
>   [info]   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
>   [info]   ... java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2390)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2366)     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec$$anonfun$2.apply(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:101)
>     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec$$anonfun$2.apply(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:88)
>     at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)  at
>   org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)   at
>   org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)     at
>   org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1682)     at
>   org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)    at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1685)   at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1679)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)  at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterEach$$super$runTest(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterEach$class.runTest(BeforeAndAfterEach.scala:221)
>     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.runTest(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)    at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1685)  at
>   org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)   at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)  at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
>     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.run(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Framework.org$scalatest$tools$Framework$$runSuite(Framework.scala:314)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:480)
>     at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)     at
>   sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)    at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:207)  at
>   sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:239)  at
>   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:245)    at
>   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:245)    at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)     at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)     at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
>     at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
>     at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)   at
>   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)    at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)    at
>   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
>     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible
>   Jackson version: 2.8.4    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:745)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2390)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2366)     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec$$anonfun$2.apply(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:101)
>     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec$$anonfun$2.apply(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:88)
>     at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)  at
>   org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)   at
>   org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)     at
>   org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1682)     at
>   org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)    at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1685)   at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1679)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)  at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterEach$$super$runTest(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterEach$class.runTest(BeforeAndAfterEach.scala:221)
>     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.runTest(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)    at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1685)  at
>   org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)   at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)  at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
>     at
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.run(CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec.scala:16)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Framework.org$scalatest$tools$Framework$$runSuite(Framework.scala:314)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:480)
>     at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)     at
>   sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)    at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at
>   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
>     at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:207)  at
>   sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:239)  at
>   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:245)    at
>   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:245)    at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)     at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)     at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
>     at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
>     at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)   at
>   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)    at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)    at
>   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
>     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [error] Could not run test
>   com.testrunner.data.processors.cloudfront.CloudfrontLogProcessorJobSpec:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems we are able to figure out:

We can add the following lines in build.sbt to override jackson version in test scope:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.5" % "test"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5" % "test"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.6.5" % "test"
```