# ExceptionInInitializerError in Scala unit test (Scalacheck, Scalatest)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, scalatest, scalacheck

I've written unit tests referring to [DataframeGenerator example](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/DataFrameGenerator), which allows you to generate mock dataframes on the fly

After having executed the following commands successfully

```
sbt clean
sbt update
sbt compile
```

I get the errors shown in output upon running either of the following commands

```
sbt assembly
sbt test -- -oF
```

Output

```
...
[info] SearchClicksProcessorTest:
17/11/24 14:19:04 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/11/24 14:19:07 WARN SparkContext: Using an existing SparkContext; some configuration may not take effect.
17/11/24 14:19:18 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
17/11/24 14:19:18 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
17/11/24 14:19:19 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
[info] - testExplodeMap *** FAILED ***
[info]   ExceptionInInitializerError was thrown during property evaluation.
[info]     Message: "None"
[info]     Occurred when passed generated values (
[info]   
[info]     )
[info] - testFilterByClicks *** FAILED ***
[info]   NoClassDefFoundError was thrown during property evaluation.
[info]     Message: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
[info]     Occurred when passed generated values (
[info]   
[info]     )
[info] - testGetClicksData *** FAILED ***
[info]   NoClassDefFoundError was thrown during property evaluation.
[info]     Message: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
[info]     Occurred when passed generated values (
[info]   
[info]     )
...
[info] *** 3 TESTS FAILED ***
[error] Failed: Total 6, Failed 3, Errors 0, Passed 3
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         com.company.spark.ml.pipelines.search.SearchClicksProcessorTest
[error] (root/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 73 s, completed 24 Nov, 2017 2:19:28 PM
```

Things that I've tried unsuccessfully

- Running sbt test with F flag to show full stacktrace (no stacktrace output appears as shown above)
- Re-build the project in IntelliJ Idea

My questions are

- What could be the possible cause of this error?
- How can I enable the stack-trace output in SBT to be able to debug it?

---

EDIT-1
My unit-test class contains several methods like below

```
class SearchClicksProcessorTest extends FunSuite with Checkers {
  import spark.implicits._

  test("testGetClicksData") {
    val schemaIn = StructType(List(
      StructField("rank", IntegerType),
      StructField("city_id", IntegerType),
      StructField("target", IntegerType)
    ))
    val schemaOut = StructType(List(
      StructField("clicked_res_rank", IntegerType),
      StructField("city_id", IntegerType),
    ))
    val dataFrameGen = DataframeGenerator.arbitraryDataFrame(spark.sqlContext, schemaIn)

    val property = Prop.forAll(dataFrameGen.arbitrary) { dfIn: DataFrame =>
      dfIn.cache()
      val dfOut: DataFrame = dfIn.transform(SearchClicksProcessor.getClicksData)

      dfIn.schema === schemaIn &&
        dfOut.schema === schemaOut &&
        dfIn.filter($"target" === 1).count() === dfOut.count()
    }
    check(property)
  }
}
```

while `build.sbt` looks like this

```
// core settings
organization := "com.company"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

name := "repo-name"
version := "0.0.1"

// cache options
offline := false
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)

// aggregate options
aggregate in assembly := false
aggregate in update := false

// fork options
fork in Test := true

//common libraryDependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  scalaTest,
  typesafeConfig,
  ...
  scalajHttp
)

libraryDependencies ++= allAwsDependencies
libraryDependencies ++= SparkDependencies.allSparkDependencies

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf") => MergeStrategy.discard
  ...
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}

lazy val module-1 = project in file("directory-1")

lazy val module-2 = (project in file("directory-2")).
  dependsOn(module-1).
  aggregate(module-1)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  dependsOn(module-2).
  aggregate(module-2)
```

Comment: Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/216) and consider explaining the queries asked there

Comment: Whats your build file & source code for the test look like?

Comment: My guess is that the tests are executed in parallel and each tries to create a brand new `SparkSession` so I'd disable parallel test execution --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/11899723/1305344

Comment: Looks like this error has nothing to do with DataFrameGenerator by @Holden. (Trying to run tests without it also results in same error) I've narrowed down the problem to creation of dataframe using following method

spark.createDataFrame(rdd: RDD, schema: StructType)

in particular, the rdd creation from sample Seq(Row) requires spark.parallelize method, which I believe is resulting in the error

Though I still haven't been able to overcome this error, so any insight would be helpful..

Comment: I've also tried @Jacek's suggestion to disable parallelism in test without luck

Answer (score 1):

i have had a similar problem case, and after investigating I found out, that adding a `lazy` before a `val` solved my issue. My estimate is, running a Scala program with Scalatest invokes a little different initializing sequence. Where a normal scala execution initializes `val`s in an sourecode line numbers top-down order - having nested `object {...}` blocks initialized in the same way - using the same coding with Scalatest, the execution initializes the `vals`s in nested `object { ... }` blocks *before* the `val`s line-number wise *above* the `object { ... }`.

This is absolutely vague I know but deferring initialization with prefixing `val`s with `lazy` could solve the test issue here.

The crucial thing here is that it doesn't occur in normal execution, only test execution, and in my case it was only occuring when using lambdas with taps in this form:

```
...
.tap(x =>
        hook_feld_erweiterungen_hook(
          abc = theProblematicVal
        )
      )
...
```

Comment: FWIW, converting to a lazy val also helped me when I got this error. I happened to have scalatest configured, but was getting the error on a spark submit. The error mentioned reflection which I think might be because of spark.

Answer (score 0):

P.S. Please read [comments on original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469833/exceptionininitializererror-in-scala-unit-test-scalacheck-scalatest/47566902#comment81898889_47469833) before reading this answer

---

- Even the popular solution of [overriding SBT's transitive dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869367/spark-unit-test-fails-with-exceptionininitializererror-with-latest-version-of) over `faster-xml.jackson` didn't work for me; in that some more changes were required (`ExceptionInInitializerError` was gone but some other error cropped up)
- Finally (in addition to above mentioned fix) I ended up creating `DataFrame`s in a different way (as opposed to `StructType` used here). I created them as

  `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(MyType)).toDF()`

  where `MyType` is a `case class` as per the *schema* of `DataFrame`
- While implementing this solution, I encountered a small problem that while *datatypes* of *schema* generated from `case class` were correct, the `nullability` of fields was often mismatching; fix for this issue was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193958/)

---

Here I'm *blatantly admitting* that I'm not sure what was the correct fix: `faster-xml.jackson` dependency or the alternate way of creating `DataFrame`, so please feel free to fill the lapses in understanding / investigating the issue